# Sylius Customizing Form Customer

Tags: php, symfony, sylius

I'm following the tutorial on the doc of Sylius to customize a form.

Here is what I have :

src\AppBundle\Form\Extension\CustomerProfileTypeExtension.php :

```
<?php

 namespace AppBundle\Form\Extension;

use Sylius\Bundle\CustomerBundle\Form\Type\CustomerProfileType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractTypeExtension;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;


final class CustomerProfileTypeExtension extends AbstractTypeExtension
{
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
{
    // Adding new fields works just like in the parent form type.
    $builder->add('contactHours', TextType::class, [
        'required' => false,
        'label' => 'app.form.customer.contact_hours',
    ]);

    // To remove a field from a form simply call ->remove(`fieldName`).
    // $builder->remove('gender');

    // You can change the label by adding again the same field with a changed `label` parameter.
    $builder->add('lastName', TextType::class, [
        'label' => 'app.form.customer.surname',
    ]);
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function getExtendedType(): string
{
    return CustomerProfileType::class;
}
}
```

src\AppBundle\Entity\Customer.php :

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Sylius\Component\Core\Model\Customer as BaseCustomer;

class Customer extends BaseCustomer
{
/**
 * @var string|null
 */
private $contactHours;

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getContactHours(): ?string
{
    return $this->contactHours;
} 

/**
 * @param string $contactHours
 */
public function setContactHours(?string $contactHours): void
{
    $this->contactHours = $contactHours;
}
}
```

AppBundle/Resources/config/services.yml : 
    services:
     ....
        app.form.extension.type.customer_profile:
        class: AppBundle\Form\Extension\CustomerProfileTypeExtension
        tags:
            - { name: form.type_extension, extended_type: Sylius\Bundle\CustomerBundle\Form\Type\CustomerProfileType }

app\Resources\SyliusShopBundle\views\Account\profileUpdate.html.twig

```
<div class="two fields">
    <div class="field">{{ form_row(form.birthday) }}</div>
    <div class="field">{{ form_row(form.contactHours) }}</div>
</div>
```

Sylius 1.0.4.

I've got "app.form.customer.surname" as Expected in the label for the lastname.
But my field "contactHours" doesn't appear...

Any idea ?
Is my "app\Resources\SyliusShopBundle\views\Account\profileUpdate.html.twig" ok ?

Answer (score 6):

I just find out I should copy `\vendor\sylius\sylius\src\Sylius\Bundle\AdminBundle\Resources\views\Customer\_form.html.twig` to `app\Resources\SyliusAdminBundle\views\Customer\_form.html.twig` and then modify it according to my needs.

Here is my modified code:

`app\Resources\SyliusAdminBundle\views\Customer\_form.html.twig`:

```
....
    <div class="ui segment">
        <h4 class="ui dividing header">{{ 'sylius.ui.extra_information'|trans }}</h4>
        {{ form_row(form.contactHours) }}
        {{ form_row(form.birthday) }}
        {{ form_row(form.phoneNumber) }}
        {{ form_row(form.subscribedToNewsletter) }}
    </div>
....
```